# Can a file references be automatically replaced by project references within solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation

I need to replace all file references within quite big solution with project references where it is possible.
Can this tedious task be performed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is turned out quite simple to create Visual Studio Add-in that preforms it for me.

Here the add-in code that performs dirty work:

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
{
    handled = false;

    LogMessage(string.Format("Start investigation at {0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

    if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
    {
        if(commandName == "ReferenceDoctor.Connect.ReferenceDoctor")
        {
            foreach (Project project in _applicationObject.Solution.Projects)
            {
                VSProject vsProject = project.Object as VSProject;
                if (vsProject != null)
                {
                    foreach (Reference reference in vsProject.References)
                    {
                        // if it not project reference
                        if (reference.SourceProject == null)
                        {
                            string refPath = reference.Path;
                            string refAssemblyName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(refPath);

                            Project refProject = FindProjectWithinSolution(refAssemblyName);

                            // if within solution found project with suitable name
                            if (refProject != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    //replace reference with project reference
                                    reference.Remove();
                                    vsProject.References.AddProject(refProject);

                                    LogMessage(string.Format(" [{0}] Reference to {1} replaced. ({2} -> {3})", vsProject.Project.Name, refAssemblyName, refPath, refProject.FullName));
                                }
                                catch (Exception exc)
                                {
                                    LogMessage(string.Format(" [{0}] ERROR during replacing reference to {1} ({2} -> {3}): {4}", vsProject.Project.Name, refAssemblyName, refPath, refProject.FullName, exc.Message));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            LogMessage(string.Format("Completed at {0} {1}\r\n", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

            handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}

private Project FindProjectWithinSolution(string projectName)
{
    foreach (Project project in _applicationObject.Solution.Projects)
    {
        VSProject vsProject = project.Object as VSProject;
        if (vsProject != null)
        {
            if (string.Compare(vsProject.Project.Name, projectName, ignoreCase: true) == 0)
            {
                return project;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I also found useful extension that switches from file reference to project reference when some project is added and inversely when it deleted:
http://markkemper1.blogspot.ru/2011/09/project-to-file-reference-switcher-for.html

Full add-in code that I use: [here](http://pastebin.com/r1EJF8fZ)